# How to update npm on Openshift Cartridge Jenkins Server?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, openshift

I've just set up a **Jenkins Server Cartridge** from **Openshift** and I have a problem with **npm** due to the old version installed on the server (1.1.37).

Openshift doesn't allow us to root on the server so I can't update node/npm by the classic way.

I just had to scour the internet for a solution unsuccessfully so I figured someone may have a solution here.

**edit:**
The only answer from Openshift support service was: That is currently the version of npm that we support on our servers.